# Check if object is NOT of type (!= equivalent for "IS") - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

This works just fine:

```
    protected void txtTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox) {...}

    }
```

Is there a way to check if sender is NOT a TextBox, some kind of an equivalent of != for "is"?

Please, don't suggest moving the logic to ELSE{} :)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

This is one way:

```
if (!(sender is TextBox)) {...}
```

Comment: For this particular situation I prefer if (sender is TextBox == false). Less clunky syntax like this.

Comment: @hmemcpy: Personally, i cringe whenever i see a comparison to a boolean constant. Probably my C background showing through... Still, makes my skin crawl, and there's no way i'd leave it alone in code i was editing.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik imo if you're going to write logically inverted statements with verbosity for clarity that it becomes more clear to write it as `if (false == sender is TextBox)`

Comment: @Shog9 I started programming a few years ago (and definitely not with C), and I never understood why people use == false or use  false ==: it's not more intuitive to me at all and I always prefer ! over it. It's just - redundant.

Comment: After reading the commentary above, I think it is clearer to use `false` rather than negation. The use of the word `is` can be enough visual distraction that a mere glance through the code could easily miss the !

Comment: any good material or reasons why there is no 'isNot' key word.

Comment: @Mafii You're forced to if it's a `Nullable<bool>` or `bool?`.

Answer (score 24):

C# 9 allows using the [not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#logical-patterns) operator. You can just use

```
if (sender is not TextBox) {...}
```

instead of

```
if (!(sender is TextBox)) {...}
```

Answer (score 8):

Couldn't you also do the more verbose "old" way, before the `is` keyword:

```
if (sender.GetType() != typeof(TextBox)) { // ... }
```

Comment: Sure, you could, but do note that the "is" keyword matches any object derived from TextBox, whereas this typeof() check only matches TextBoxes.

Answer (score 3):

Two well-known ways of doing it are :

1) Using IS operator:

```
if (!(sender is TextBox)) {...}
```

2) Using AS operator (useful if you also need to work with the textBox instance) :

```
var textBox = sender as TextBox;  
if (sender == null) {...}
```

Comment: For future readers: The difference between `is` and `as` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)

Answer (score -2):

If you use inheritance like:

```
public class BaseClass
{}
public class Foo : BaseClass
{}
public class Bar : BaseClass
{}
```

...
Null resistant

```
if (obj?.GetType().BaseType != typeof(Bar)) { // ... }
```

or

```
if (!(sender is Foo)) { //... }
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this.

```
var cont= textboxobject as Control;
if(cont.GetType().Name=="TextBox")
{
   MessageBox.show("textboxobject is a textbox");
}
```

Comment: Why the initial `as Control` line, does it behave differently compared to `GetType()` on an `object`? Other than that, string comparison for something like this is not refactor friendly code.

Comment: This is wrong on several levels. There is no need to do the initial "as" if you are going to do the type check by name. Also, don't ever hard code things like "TextBox". If you wanted to do the check that way, do this instead using FullName instead of just Name: if (cont.GetType().FullName == typeof(TextBox).FullName) {}. You don't want to use Name and leave out the namespace in case you create your own custom control in a different namespace and call it TextBox.