# How to check if an object is not of a particular type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to check if an object is not of a particular type.  I know how to check if something *is* of a particular type:

```
if (t is TypeA)
{
   ...
}
```

but

```
if (t isnt TypeA)
{
   ...
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if object is NOT of type (!= equivalent for "IS") - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529944/check-if-object-is-not-of-type-equivalent-for-is-c-sharp)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**UPDATE 2020-10-30:**

Times are changing. Starting from C# 9.0 you can use more natural way of checking it:

```
if(t is not TypeA) { ... }
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

C# is not quite natural language ;)
Use this one

```
if(!(t is TypeA))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

if you want not only *check*, you can use [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator.

```
var a = t as TypeA;
if(a!= null)
   //use a..
```

In this way, if you want use a type after check, you avoid double casting..

Comment: I don't think this works if a is null before the cast.

Answer (score 5):

Extensions methods to the rescue!!

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool Isnt(this object source, Type targetType)
    {
        return source.GetType() != targetType;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
if (t.Isnt(typeof(TypeA)))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I did this, but I also created an extension of "IS" as well just so the code looks similar -e.g.  t.IsA(xxx) , t.IsNotA(xxx). yes I know it's not needed, but it looks better to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing a `TypeA x = (TypeA)t;` inside the if block then a better way is

```
TypeA x = t as TypeA
if(x != null)
{
...
}
```

This causes only one time type checking rather than twice.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  you may want to use:

```
if (t.GetType()==typeof(TypeA))
{
   ...
}
if (t.GetType()!=typeof(TypeA))
{
  ...
}
```

---

Long answer:

So.  Be aware that you're asking if it's a particular type.  `is` doesn't tell you if it's a particular type - it tells you if it's a particular type or *any descendant of* that type.

So if you have two classes, Animal, and Cat : Animal, and felix is a cat, then

```
if (felix is Animal)
{
    //returns true
}
if (felix.GetType() == typeof(Animal))
{
    //does not
}
```

If it's not important to you, inherited classes are okay, then don't worry about it, use `!(felix is Animal)` as others mentioned, and you're fine!  (You're probably fine.)

But if you need to be sure felix is specifically an Animal, then you need to ask if `t.GetType()==typeof(TypeA)`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually stick the null and type checking all in one line:

```
if (t == null || !(t is TypeA)) {
  ...
}
```

If TypeA is a struct, you'll need to handle it slightly differently again:

```
if (t == null || t.GetType() != typeof(TypeA)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below example for `getType()`:

```
object obj = new object();
obj.GetType();

string s;
s.GetType();

List<string> StringList = new List<string>();
StringList.GetType();
```

Comment: Link only answers are not that efficient here. Please edit your answer with relevant code so that it's easier for everyone to read what's important to the subject.